# Use of URLConnection on Samsung Galaxy s2

Tags: android, http

I am using an instance of `URLConnection` to download pictures from a web server. This works well on most phones.

I used http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/ as inspiration for doing parallel downloads.

I call both `setConnectTimeout(timeout)` and `setReadTimeout(timeout)` so that I can recover from timeouts as I start a number of threads which fetch images in parallel.

On the Samsung Galaxy s2 phone the timeouts are ignored and some of the threads downloading hang for several minutes before an exception is thrown and the download is retried - the download succeeds second time around.

An exception which is thrown looks like this:

```
DownloadTask, network timeout (attempt #0)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to host (port 80) after 1000ms
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:150)
libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
..
```

Is this known broken behavior on Samsung Galaxy s2?

Android version: 4.0.4.

Comment: how many threads are you opening at the same time?

Comment: 8 threads. No timeout when I use 4 threads.

Comment: could it be that the server has a limitation on the amount of concurrent connections? I know that most browsers by default allow only 4 simultaneous connections

Comment: The same code works on another phone with the same server.

Comment: I think that networking might not be the problem here. The correct exception is thrown and is refers to "1000ms" which is the amount of ms I used for `setConnectTimeout`. 

Starting 8 threads might be too much for this Samsung phone, as one or more of the threads is put to sleep and wakes up several minutes later where this exception is thrown.